# Problems opening zips in java created with 7-zip

Tags: java, zip, 7zip

I try to open a zip-file with the following java-code:

```
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:\\test.zip");
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
    }
    zipFile.close();
```

gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
    at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:531)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:513)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.nextElement(ZipFile.java:483)
```

when reading a zip file containing files german "Umlaute" (ä,ü,ö...) which was created using 7-zip. As the default encoding used by `ZipFile` is UTF-8.

So, I try to find out the encoding used by 7-zip (windows 7, 64 bit) when zipping files within the GUI. Apparently it's not UTF-8..